# Kibana 4 querying on .Net Timespan Field

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4

I'm new to Kibana and have created some dashboards and such, so far so good.

One issue I'm having is with a Timespan field, this is a .net field and has the format of 00:00:00.0053259

Ideally I'd like a query to show all with a timespan > 1 second. Is this possible in Kibana, currently this field has been indexed as a string after being pushed to ElasticSearch using Logstash.

Does the template for this need altered to convert to another format, if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

First, you must write a pattern to extract the timespan data from the message:

```
%{INT:hour}[:]%{INT:min}[:]%{INT:sec}[.]%{INT:micro}
```

Then you can use [ruby filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html) to transform each field and sum then:

```
ruby {
    code => "event['timespan_total'] = 3600 * event['hour'].to_f + 60 * event['min'].to_f + event['secs'].to_f + event['micro'] * 0.0000001"
}
```